# Странное непостоянное исключение javaFx

Tags: java, javafx, исключения

При работе программы через некоторое время выбрасывается исключение, но не указана строка кода, которая сгенерировала его. После этого интерфейс перестает отвечать на запросы, но другой поток спокойно продолжает свою роботу. При чем, после первого исключения, оно начинает повторяться постоянно.
В чем проблема?

код - https://pastebin.com/VBcnBgpv

исключение:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.scenario.animation.AbstractMasterTimer.timePulseImpl(AbstractMasterTimer.java:344)
    at com.sun.scenario.animation.AbstractMasterTimer$MainLoop.run(AbstractMasterTimer.java:267)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:506)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:490)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$404(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: У меня для вас ужасная новость: классы JavaFX не потокобезопасны. При разработке многопоточной программы с GUI надо быть предельно осторожным и использовать специально предназначенные для этого средства библиотеки. Для JavaFX - это javafx.concurrent.

Comment: спасибо большое, буду разбираться. Даже и не знал о таком